# Serving a XUL application

Tags: firefox, xul

I wonder if it would be possible to *serve* a **XUL** rich application (**not** an extension) (I would create some files and package the application on the fly on the server side according to the request) and then the user would be able to run the application on the desktop (something like javaws for java).

How should I package the application ? What is the mime-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not want to do that since [that functionality will be removed (or at least disabled) in Firefox 4.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546857).